# Scatter Diagram out of 3-dimensional matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix in the form:

[x1 y1 x1; x2 y2 z2; ... ; xn yn zn]

Which I want to plot in a 3-Dimensional scatter-diagram.

I understand I have to use meshgrid, however, as my matrix could have any number of values I wanted to know how I could implement it as I can't preassign sizes to the various axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your matrix `M`, then simply use `M(:,1)` to get the first column out, `M(:,2)` for the second column etc. and use `scatter3`:

```
scatter3(M(:,1),M(:,2),M(:,3))
```